# How to add custom markers to Google Timeline Chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to add markers on the Google Timeline chart as shown here [Timeline Chart with Markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITJsL.png)

I am currently following the solution given here: [Google Charts Add Layer On Top Of Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614813/google-charts-add-layer-on-top-of-timeline). But, here there needs to be a timeline element only then can the marker be present over it. But, I want a way that a marker can be added without having any timeline data at that position in the row. Is there a built in feature for adding markers in Google Timelines, or a custom way which does not require adding a dummy timeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are no built-in features for adding markers.
and since the answer you reference is a custom solution,
we can modify the solution to fit our needs.

we don't necessarily need a timeline element in order to place a marker.
but we do need data, in order to draw the timeline,
on which to place the markers.

out of the box, the timeline will limit the x-axis to the range of dates found in the data.

but we can set a custom x-axis range, to make it larger,
and allow more room for markers, where there are no timeline elements.

```
hAxis: {
  minValue: dateRangeStart,
  maxValue: dateRangeEnd,
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['timeline']
}).then(function () {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Row'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Bar'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'Start'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'End'});
  var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Row 1', 'A-1', new Date(currentYear, 0, 1), new Date(currentYear, 2, 31)],
    ['Row 1', 'A-2', new Date(currentYear, 3, 1), new Date(currentYear, 5, 30)],
    ['Row 2', 'B-1', new Date(currentYear, 6, 1), new Date(currentYear, 8, 31)],
    ['Row 2', 'B-2', new Date(currentYear, 9, 1), new Date(currentYear, 11, 31)]
  ]);
  var dataTableGroup = google.visualization.data.group(dataTable, [0]);
  var dateRangeStart = new Date(currentYear - 1, 0, 1);
  var dateRangeEnd = new Date(currentYear + 1, 11, 31);
  var rowHeight = 44;
  var options = {
    height: (dataTableGroup.getNumberOfRows() * rowHeight) + rowHeight,
    hAxis: {
      minValue: dateRangeStart,
      maxValue: dateRangeEnd,
    }
  };

  function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }

  // add custom marker
  function addMarkers(events) {
    var baseline;
    var baselineBounds;
    var chartElements;
    var labelFound;
    var labelText;
    var marker;
    var markerLabel;
    var markerSpan;
    var rowLabel;
    var svg;
    var svgNS;
    var timeline;
    var timelineUnit;
    var timelineWidth;
    var timespan;
    var xCoord;
    var yCoord;

    // initialize chart elements
    baseline = null;
    svg = null;
    svgNS = null;
    timeline = null;
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('svg');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      svg = chartElements[0];
      svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      timeline = chartElements[0];
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('path');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      baseline = chartElements[0];
    }
    if ((svg === null) || (timeline === null) || (baseline === null)) {
      return;
    }
    timelineWidth = parseFloat(timeline.getAttribute('width'));
    baselineBounds = baseline.getBBox();
    timespan = dateRangeEnd.getTime() - dateRangeStart.getTime();
    timelineUnit = (timelineWidth - baselineBounds.x) / timespan;

    // add events
    events.forEach(function (event) {
      // find row label
      rowLabel = dataTable.getValue(event.row, 0);
      chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
      if (chartElements.length > 0) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartElements, function(label) {
          if (label.textContent.indexOf('…') > -1) {
            labelText = label.textContent.replace('…', '');
          } else {
            labelText = label.textContent;
          }
          if (rowLabel.indexOf(labelText) > -1) {
            markerLabel = label.cloneNode(true);
          }
        });
      }

      // calculate placement
      markerSpan = event.date.getTime() - dateRangeStart.getTime();

      // add label
      markerLabel.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'start');
      markerLabel.setAttribute('fill', event.color);
      markerLabel.setAttribute('x', (baselineBounds.x + (timelineUnit * markerSpan) + 6));
      markerLabel.textContent = event.name;
      svg.appendChild(markerLabel);

      // add marker
      xCoord = (baselineBounds.x + (timelineUnit * markerSpan) - 4);
      yCoord = parseFloat(markerLabel.getAttribute('y'));
      switch (event.type) {
        case 'triangle':
          marker = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'polygon');
          marker.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
          marker.setAttribute('stroke', event.color);
          marker.setAttribute('stroke-width', '3');
          marker.setAttribute('points', xCoord + ',' + (yCoord - 10) + ' ' + (xCoord - 5) + ',' + yCoord + ' ' + (xCoord + 5) + ',' + yCoord);
          svg.appendChild(marker);
          break;

        case 'circle':
          marker = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'circle');
          marker.setAttribute('cx', xCoord);
          marker.setAttribute('cy', yCoord - 5);
          marker.setAttribute('r', '6');
          marker.setAttribute('stroke', event.color);
          marker.setAttribute('stroke-width', '3');
          marker.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
          svg.appendChild(marker);
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    addMarkers([
      {row: 0, date: new Date(currentYear - 1, 1, 11), name: 'Event 1', type: 'triangle', color: 'red'},
      {row: 1, date: new Date(currentYear + 1, 5, 23), name: 'Event 2', type: 'circle', color: 'purple'},
      {row: 3, date: new Date(currentYear + 1, 8, 2), name: 'Event 3', type: 'triangle', color: 'magenta'}
    ]);
  });

  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  drawChart();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```