# Google Developer Chart Timelines - Adding a header

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-developer-tools

Is there a way to add headers to the google chart timeline?
Example (Stage 1, Stage 2):
[image]

Comment: nothing out of the box, you could possibly modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825049/how-to-add-custom-markers-to-google-timeline-chart/63828909#63828909) to meet your needs...

Comment: I will check this out, thanks