# How to add vertical lines and annotations Google timeline chart

Tags: google-visualization

I am using a google timeline similar to the code snippet below. I want my chart to look like the one below. I have managed to get everything to work expect how to add the dashed lines and text notation. Unfortunately, when I am searching for annotations I keep getting the AnnotatedTimeline, which is a different google chart.

Is there a simple way to do this?

[image]

```html
       <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {
            var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
            var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
            dataTable.addRows([
              [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
              [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
              [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);
    
            chart.draw(dataTable);
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="timeline" style="height: 180px;"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This may seem similar to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872915/vertical-reference-line-in-google-timeline-visualization, but the differences are that I want it to draw when the document is ready, and the lines and text should always be there, not on mouse over. Plus I want to add multiple lines and text. I would rather just add this stuff after the chart is drawn if possible.

Comment: you can use [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48509661/5090771) from that post. the `addMarker` function can be used multiple times. -- here is a [similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63828909/5090771)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by finding the position of the rects. I started by drawing divs for each line I would want to show. Then after the timeline is draw I repositions those divs based on the location of the rectangle. I was not able to get a good minimal working snippet here because of the window positions used in the snippet code, but I got pretty close. In my own code I have it working perfectly.

```css
.hline {
            border-left: 5px solid black;
            height: 100px;
            position:absolute;
            visibility:hidden;
            top:144px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="timeline" style="height: 180px;"></div>
        
        
        <div id = "Hline1" class= "hline" > <div style = "position: relative; top:-18px">HLine1</div>
        <div id = "Hline2" class= "hline" > <div style = "position: relative; top:-18px">HLine2</div>
        <div id = "Hline3" class= "hline" > <div style = "position: relative; top:-18px">HLine3</div>
        
        </div>
      </body>
      
      <script>
        var options = {
                          timeline: { showRowLabels: false }
                        };
        const lime="#00ff00" //color for average time
          google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {
            var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
            var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Project Stage',  });
                dataTable.addColumn({  type: 'string', id: 'Bar'});
                dataTable.addColumn({  type: 'string', role: 'style'});
                dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
                dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
              dataTable.addRows([
                          [ 'Washington','Washington',lime, new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
                          [ 'Adams', 'Adams',lime,     new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
                          [ 'Jefferson','Jefferson',lime,  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);
                
                        chart.draw(dataTable,options);
                      
          
          
          function redraw (){
            var rects = $('rect') //get all rectangles on plot.
            
            function checkColor(arr){
                var results = [];
                for (let i of arr){
                var colorCheck=$(i).attr('fill')
                var x =$(i).attr('x')
                var width = $(i).attr('width')  
                var x2 =parseFloat(x)+parseFloat(width)
                    
                    if(colorCheck == lime){results.push(x2)}
                    };
                    return results
                };
                
            var linPositions = checkColor(rects) //get x coordinates for vertical lines

            var yStart = $('rect')
            //console.log(linPositions)
            yStart = $(yStart[0]).offset().top;
            xMargin=$("#timeline").offset().left;

    
            
            var yHeight = $('rect')
            yHeight = $(yHeight[0]).attr('height');
            

            var lineNames=['Hline1','Hline2','Hline3']

            
            for (let i = 0; i < linPositions.length; i++) {
                var position = linPositions[i]+xMargin+"px"
                var newTop = i*yHeight + yStart
                
                /* set line information based on current chart positions */
                document.getElementById(lineNames[i]).style.left = position;
                document.getElementById(lineNames[i]).style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById(lineNames[i]).style.top = newTop;
                document.getElementById(lineNames[i]).style.height = yHeight;

            
            };
            
        };  

        redraw()    
        
        function resizeChart () {
            chart.draw(dataTable, options);

        }
        if (document.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('resize', resizeChart);
            window.addEventListener('resize', redraw)
        }
        else if (document.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeChart);
            window.attachEvent('onresize', redraw);
        }
        else {
            window.resize = resizeChart;
            window.resize = redraw;
        }
    
        
        }
          
        </script>
      
    </html>
```